# Solve the system of equations $x + y^2 + z^3 = 3; y + z^2 + x^3 = 3; z + x^2 + y^3 = 3$ (where x,y,z are positive real numbers)

Tags: systems-of-equations

It seems that $x=y=z=1$ is the only solution, but I can't find how to prove it. I've tried defining $a=x-1; b=y-1; c=z-1$, but with no success. Any ideas?

Geometrically, each equation defines a 3D surface. All 3 surfaces are identical, except they are oriented along different axes. We're looking for their intersection.

Comment: I checked using wolfram alpha and all other solutions are have imaginary values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\;\; (x-1) &+\;\; (y-1)\,(y+1) &+\;\; (z-1)\,(z^2+z+1) &= 0
\\ \;\; (x-1)\,(x^2+x+1) &+\;\;(y-1) &+\;\; (z-1)\,(z+1) &= 0
\\ \;\; (x-1)\,(x+1) &+\;\;(y-1)\,(y^2+y+1) &+\;\; (z-1) &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Regarding it as a linear homogeneous system in $x-1, y-1, z-1$, its determinant is:

$$
\Delta = 
\begin{vmatrix}
   1 &y+1 &z^2+z+1
\\ x^2+x+1 &1 &z+1
\\ x+1 &y^2+y+1 &1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

After routine calculations courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%7B+%7B1%2C+y%2B1%2C+z%5E2%2Bz%2B1%7D%2C+%7Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1%2C+1%2C+z%2B1%7D%2C+%7Bx%2B1%2C+y%5E2%2By%2B1%2C+1%7D+%7D), and using that $x,y,z \gt 0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta &= x^2 y^2 z^2 + x^2 y^2 z + x^2 y^2 + x^2 y z^2 + x^2 y z + x^2 z^2 + x^2 z + x y^2 z^2
\\ &\;\;\;\; + x y^2 z + x y^2 + x y z^2 + 2 x y z + x y + x z + y^2 z^2 + y z^2 + y z
\\ &\gt 0
\end{align}
$$

It follows that the only solution is $x-1=y-1=z-1=0\,$.

Comment: No, you can’t solve the system of equations as if it were a linear system like that. The parameters depend on the variables $x,y,z$

Comment: @NN2 Yes, you can. Define the auxiliary variables $a=x-1, b=y-1, c=z-1$ (like the OP did in the question), then you have a linear homogeneous system in $a,b,c$ with coefficients that are polynomials in $x,y,z$. If the determinant of the system is proved to be non-$0$ (as is the case here) then the only solution is $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: @dxiv sorry that I'm looking at your answer only now but what about : $\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=0\\x^2+y^2=0\end{cases}$ there is obviously a single solution whereas determinant is $\left|\begin{array} 0x&y\\x&y\end{array}\right|=0$

Comment: @Olivier That is true, but unrelated. Point is that *if* the determinant is $\ne 0$ *then* the trivial solution is the only solution. What happens if the determinant $=0$ is of no interest and no consequence here.

Comment: Ok @dxiv. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Mathematica confirms that there is only one solution:

```
Solve[{x + y^2 + z^3 == 3, y + z^2 + x^3 == 3, z + x^2 + y^3 == 3}, {x, y, z}, PositiveReals]
```

{{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1}}

Comment: Welcome to MSW. That's could be a comment, but not an answer.