# $x+y^2+z^3=y+z^2+x^3=z+x^2+y^3=3$

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

This was a high school entrance exam problem.

> Find all real solutions for $x,y,z$: $$\begin{cases}x+y^2+z^3=3\\y+z^2+x^3=3\\z+x^2+y^3=3\end{cases}$$

I believe the intended solution uses basic algebra only, but it's allowed to use higher level maths such as calculus, elliptic curves or 3d geometry if we can.

**My attempt:** I guess $(1,1,1)$ is the only solution, so I tried substituting $x=x_1+1$ and similar for $y$ and $z$, but to no avail.

The usual way of solving a system of equations yields

$$x+y^2=3+(x^2+y^3-3)^3$$
$$x^3+y=3-(x^2+y^3-3)^2$$

and I can't proceed further.

Comment: You can graph $f(x,y)=0$ on some online graphing calculators

Comment: Btw which entrace exam is this?,..just curious..

Comment: The resultant of your two equations is a single polynomial in y, of degree 27.  Its only real root seems to be $y=1$ according to Wolfram Alpha

Comment: The vector $(x-y,y-z,z-x)$ is orthogonal to $1,y+z,z^2+zx+x^2)$ and two similar vectors.  Perhaps you can show they are linearly independent, with a nonzero triple product.  Then the first vector must be zero?

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181543/solve-the-system-of-equations-x-y2-z3-3-y-z2-x3-3-z-x2-y) has another solution but only for positive reals.